# Dynamic Gutenberg Block not initializing Slick Carousel in Editor, no JS is executed at all

Tags: wordpress, server-side-rendering, slick.js, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I've created a dynamic Gutenberg Block with `<ServerSideRender />` and the Block is rendered using PHP. A cronjob imports customer reviews into a MySQL database every night. The Block displays those customer reviews inside a Slick Carousel.

Everything is working great in the frontend but the Block won't initialize the Slick Carousel in the editor (backend). It looks like no JavaScript is executed at all. I've stripped down my rendering PHP file to this:

**index.php**

```
/**
 * Server-side rendering of the dynamic 'mna/testimonial' block.
 */
function render_block_mna_testimonial($attributes) {
  $foo = '<h1>I am confused</h1>';
  $bar = '<script type="text/javascript">alert("HEY HEY");</script>';
  return $foo.$bar;
}

/**
 * Registers the 'mna/testimonial' block on server.
 */
function register_block_mna_testimonial() {
  register_block_type('mna/testimonial', array(
    'attributes' => array(
        ...
    ),
    'render_callback' => 'render_block_mna_testimonial',
  ));
}
add_action('init', 'register_block_mna_testimonial');
```

Behaviour in the **frontend**: H1 is displayed, Alert is displayed

Behaviour in the **editor**:  H1 is displayed, Alert is **not** displayed

I added setTimeout out of desperation `<script type="text/javascript">setTimeout(function(){ alert("HEY HEY"); }, 10000);</script>` and got the same result, still no alert.

I tried using `customEvent` as coderaaron described in this comment on GitHub: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/12603#issuecomment-513945557

But since even the alert doesn't work it won't execute `document.addEventListener` either.

Any ideas why the JS is not beeing executed in the editor?

Comment: Have you tried [enqueuing the JavaScript in PHP for the Admin/Editor](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/)?

Comment: No, since the JavaScript should be executed on both, the frontend and the editor/wp-admin and I have to pass the values from `$attributes`, while initializing the Slick Carousel, I've actually used an inline script block inside the rendering PHP file like shown above.

I can see the inline script block in the DOM, but it won't execute in the editor/wp-admin and I have no logical explanation why.

Comment: use `wp.domReady`

Comment: Did you fix this?

Comment: Better late than never: it's not possible to render and/or execute JavaScript in render_callback php code. At least not in a reliable way.
However it's possible to use React in the frontend like the WooCommerce team describes here: https://developer.woocommerce.com/2021/11/15/how-does-woocommerce-blocks-render-interactive-blocks-in-the-frontend/
I'm exhausted trying to build nice things with Gutenberg, they should've implemented something to render dynamic/interactive blocks in the frontend right from the beginning.